# How to define backgrounds for background slider and how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

i am trying to make an background slider for a restaurant. and for this reason i used gatsby-image-background-slider. when i executed "gatsby develop" it shows no error while execution but when i try to browse in localhost it shows the error "×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'backgrounds' of undefined"

the source code can be found here [enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-khayyam-rfu67?file=/src/pages/index.js)

i wanted to use carousel but i thought it would be better to use this plugin. this is my first try in gatsby. i have installed the plugin and tried the query in graphql. according to gatsby-image-background-slider document, there is no mention of giving the directory to the backgrounds. i tried to input some in relativepath but it is showing error and it is not mentioned in document.

is there any idea how can i get rid of this error or hoa can i have a background slider or carousel like thing in optimizing way?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your BackgroundSection component as:

```
export default function BackgroundSection({
  img,
  styleClass,
  children,
  title,
  query // you forgot this
}) {
  return (
    <BackgroundSlider className={styleClass} fluid={img} query={query}>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-xl-9 col-md-9 col-md-12">
            <div class="slider_text text-center bold">
              <div>
                <h1>{title}</h1>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h1>{title}</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      {children}
    </BackgroundSlider>
  )
}
```

You **forgot** to include query and **pass** that query into BackgroundSLider component

Comment: not working. now it's showing this: TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
callback
C:/Myfiles/for_react/Gatsbyjs/src/index.js:104
  101 |  const callback = function(){     
  102 |            const index = indexRef.current;
  103 |   
> 104 |   bgWrappers[index].style.opacity = 0;
  105 |   bgWrappers[(index + 1) % length].style.opacity = 1;
  106 | 
  107 |   subWrappers[index].style.opacity = 0;

Comment: i have done it with by importing {Carousel} from gatsby-bootstrap but i wanted to give a try with backgroundslider. but still no luck

Comment: I didn't have time to look into code more deeply... Maybe there's some bug in backgroundslider

Comment: thanx for your effort so far....will look into it after finishing this

Answer (score 1):

If you specified images to include (images={[]}) be sure that the image name exists in your image folder